# How to change the sort order for shipping in admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, shipment-tracking

I would like the default to be UPS and not Custom Value.  Is there a way I can do this in Magento 1.9.2.4?

[image: shipment sort order]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the easiest whey. You have to copy this two files to your Theme in the adminhtml Scope

```
sales/order/shipment/create/tracking.phtml
sales/order/invoice/create/tracking.phtml
```

It's important to use the exact same folder and filename.

replace in both files this 5 lines (you will find this code at Line number 93)

```
<select name="tracking[__index__][carrier_code]" id="trackingC__index__" class="select carrier" style="width:110px;" disabled="disabled">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCarriers() as $_code=>$_name): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_name) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

with this 5 Lines:

```
<select name="tracking[__index__][carrier_code]" id="trackingC__index__" class="select carrier" style="width:110px;" disabled="disabled">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCarriers() as $_code=>$_name): ?>
    <option <?php if ($_code=="ups"): ?>selected<?php endif; ?> value="<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_name) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

The difference is in Line 3. There is a condition that checks if the option is `ups` and sets the `selected` attribute.

Comment: It would be nice if you accept the answer, so others see that this solution works